# In highcharts, the state of rangeselector buttons with custom events do not change correctly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighStocks and have implemented two buttons in order to have two views of my chart data; "All" and "last 30 days". I have defined the states for the buttons as well, but the button for "last 30 days" do not change its appearance after being clicked, even though the "All" button, does so. And the "selected" property of the chart is also updated and even the state of the button is changes, through some workarounds. Nonetheless, its appearance remains the same.

Hear is my options object:

```
    balanceChart = Highcharts.stockChart('balance-chart-section', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'ComicSans',
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: "right",
            verticalAlign: "top",
            rtl: false,
            y: 0,
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            selected: 1,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 30,
                text: 'Last 30 days',
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        this._offsetMax = 0;
                        this._offsetMin = Math.max(chartLength - 30, 0);

                        balanceChart.rangeSelector.selected = 0;
                        balanceChart.rangeSelector.buttons[0].setState(2);
                        balanceChart.rangeSelector.buttons[1].setState(0);

                    }
                },
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All',
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        this._offsetMin = 0;
                        this._offsetMax = Math.max(chartLength - 1, 0);

                        balanceChart.rangeSelector.selected = 1;
                        balanceChart.rangeSelector.buttons[1].setState(2);
                        balanceChart.rangeSelector.buttons[0].setState(0);


                    }
                }
            }],
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            buttonPosition: {
                align: 'center',
                y: 12,
            },
            inputEnabled: false,
            buttonSpacing: 30,
            buttonTheme: {
                style: {
                    fill: 'none',
                    color: '#595959',
                },
                stroke: 'none',
                padding: 10,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                height: 18,
                width: null,
                'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 10,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: '#0ec3ee',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#16aed2',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {},
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            type: 'datetime',
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            tickLength: 0,
            crosshair: {
                width: 2,
                color: 'gray',
                dashStyle: 'shortDash'
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            shared: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var points = this.points;
                var pointsLength = points.length;
                var tooltipMarkup =
                    pointsLength ? '<div class="chart__tooltip" style="margin-bottom: 5px">' + points[0].key + '</div><br/>' : '';
                var index;
                var yValue;

                for (index = 0; index < pointsLength; index += 1) {
                    yValue = (points[index].y);

                    tooltipMarkup += '<div class="chart__tooltip" style="margin-bottom: 5px">' +
                        points[index].series.name + ': <b>' + transform(number_formatter(yValue)) + '<b/>' + ' IRT' + '<br/></div>';
                }

                return tooltipMarkup;
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderColor: '#B5CAE1',
            borderRadius: 10,
            split: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 0
            },
            area: {}
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'OriginalWithSurplus',
            // data: seriesOne,
            data: seriesOneTemp,
            color: '#acdeaa',
        }, {
            name: 'Original',
            // data: seriesTwo,
            data: seriesTwoTemp,
            color: '#bcc0ff',
        }]
    });
```

Why does one of my buttons not change its appearance when clicked?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi arsalan yarveisi, The `rangeSelector` buttons seems to work correctly
without your custom code: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3Ld08eot/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek, I omitted the custom events, and modified my pointInterval and got it working! Turns out the main problem was the low number of my test data and having not set the pointIntervals together with the interference by the custom events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set correctly `count` and `type` buttons properties, you do not need to use the `click` event with custom code:

```
    buttons: [{
        type: 'day',
        count: 30,
        text: 'Last 30 days'
    }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
    }]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3Ld08eot/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector